# how to check the logs for my asp.net mvc web application which is deployed inside IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have deployed an asp.net mvc-5 web application inside IIS , now a user mentioned that he received an "Error occurred while processing your request" which indicates that an unexpected error has occurred, so can anyone adivce from where i can check the details of this error ?

Comment: Have you checked the eventvwr in that server?

Comment: i open the eventvwr but not sure where exactly i can find the IIS errors , as there are many options there.. can u adivce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)'s NuGet package. For more info visit:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

Comment: this tool will be useful for future errors is this correct ? what i want is to check the error that have been already occured..

Comment: Yes you right. But as far as I know IIS don't log your program's exceptions if you already have not configured any thing. If you have any access to the server log on to the server and visit that page locally. You can see exception detail then. Or you can set `customErrors` off in `web.config` file to view error detail remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Take A Look at this Guide, you should be able to find them in the Windows Event Viewer

[Viewing IIS Event and Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**Alternatively**

You can look at the Logs IIS Writes in the inetpub Folder.

```
c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
```

Comment: i checked the c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles but seems it does not show any exceptions details and it only show the http requests that have been received ...